# CakePHP: Use returned value from called function in calling function

Tags: php, cakephp

In my controller, I have a function (getRelatedStuff) that returns an array of values for use in my edit.ctp:

```
class MyController extends AppController {
    public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->getRelatedStuff($current['Form']['id'];
    }
    public function getRelatedStuff($id = null) {
        $this->loadModel('Related');
        $related = $this->Related->find('all', array(
            'conditions'=>array('Related.id' => $id)
        );
         return $this->set(compact('related'));
    }
}
```

This works fine when I use it in edit.ctp in a foreach loop.

```
foreach($related as $r) { 
    echo $r['Model']['field'];
}
```

However, I'm unable to use $related within my edit function itself, and I need access to that data for another purpose. Specifically, I need to set up a foreach() loop within function edit using $related. If I try to do so, or if I try debug $related within the edit function, I always get:

```
undefined variable $related in /docpath
```

What can I do to be able to use $related within my edit function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use it in the template because of this line

```
$this->set(compact('related'));
```

(It's creating `$related` var for the template to use)

But your edit action in controller does not have access to $related variable, so you should return it:

```
class MyController extends AppController {
    public function edit($id = null) {
        $related = $this->getRelatedStuff($current['Form']['id']);
        var_dump($related)
    }
    public function getRelatedStuff($id = null) {
        $this->loadModel('Related');
        $related = $this->Related->find('all', array(
            'conditions'=>array('Related.id' => $id)
        );
        $this->set(compact('related'));
        return $related
    }
}
```

Comment: But I'm already returning the variable. Look at the line again. `return $this->set(compact('related'));`

Comment: You're returning value of `$this->set` and I can't find in cackephp docs any info about what it returns. If it returns the set variable - then you need to assing this in your method `$related = $this->getRelatedStuff($current['Form']['id']`. But I really doubt `$this->set` works that way, since you can pass an array with many variables to set.

Comment: [**`Controller::set()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-Controller.html#_set) doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the function call in my edit function to the following:

```
$related = $this->getRelatedStuff(['Form']['id']);
```

I then set the variable for edit.ctp within the edit function:

```
$this->set('related', $related);
```

Lastly, I modified getRelatedStuff so that it only returned the raw variable, without setting it first:

```
return $related;
```

Comment: So basically you did what I suggested in my answer :/